How to make a REGEX pattern in mysql for 3 or more digits that are in sequence?
I've created a regex pattern to match sequences of digits that can be ascending or descending, like 12345, 123, 321, 6789, 7654, etc. However, I believe this approach may not be the most efficient or professional way to achieve this task.
Could you please provide a simpler regex expression that can match number sequences, whether ascending or descending? This is how I'm currently implementing it in Laravel
'sequential' => function ($query) {
    $query->orWhereRaw('plate_number REGEXP ?', ['\\b(123(4(5)?)?|234(5)?|345|456|567(8(9)?)?|678(9)?|789|987(6(5)?)?|876(5)?|765|654|543(2(1)?)?|432(1)?)\\b']);
},

I've attempted several approaches to create a regex pattern that accurately matches sequences of numbers. However, the regex pattern I've come up with seems unprofessional to me. Could you please verify if it's correct, or suggest a better way to achieve this?That plate ads with numbers like e.g 1234,2345, 5432,98765,... ,etc.

I've created a regex pattern to match sequences of digits that can be ascending or descending, like 12345, 123, 321, 6789, 7654, etc. Does these values to be tested are complete values (i.e. there are no any other symbols)? ot these are substrings to be found in more complex value?

Should gaps in an ascending sequence be allowed? Should 0246 match?

Is 0 not allowed?

Your regex does not match any of the following: 4567, 45678, 345678, 23456, 123456, 3456, 123456,... Are there some more rules to apply?

yes it is not tha perfect but there are no more specifice rules just sequence of numbers either ascending or descending but they should be in a sequence just

What about 0: is it not allowed?

Try:
^(?:(?<inc>1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)){2,}.|(?<dec>9(?=8)|8(?=7)|7(?=6)|6(?=5)|5(?=4)|4(?=3)|3(?=2)|2(?=1)){2,}.)$

See: regex101

Explanation

^...$: match whole string
(?:...|...): match either increasing or decreasing

(?<inc>...): increasing is defined as

1(?=2)|...: a number and a lookahead ensuring it is followed by successor
{2,}.: get this at least two numbers like this and match a third (which trough lookahead is ensured to be a successor)


(?<dec>...: do the same for decreasing




it worked ✌
Thanks alot

Similar to another answer, but looking ahead with two digits instead of one:
\b(?:(?:(?=12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89).){2,}|(?:(?=98|87|76|65|54|43|32|21).){2,}).\b

So it looks ahead ensuring that either every pair is an increasing pair or that every pair is a decreasing pair. After valid pairs there should be a break.
If you don't want to match substrings but only the whole string, then use ^ and $ instead of \b:
^(?:(?:(?=12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89).){2,}|(?:(?=98|87|76|65|54|43|32|21).){2,}).$

on regex101
NB: apparently 0 is not allowed (as it is not in your regex), so I excluded it here as well. If you want to allow inputs like 012, then you need to adapt the regex to also include 01 and 10 as valid pairs.
